# How do I correctly deserialize json that consists of a list item that includes another object?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, resttemplate

The client I am using returns json like this:

```json
[
    {
        "source": "ANY"
    }
]
```

That is, the element of the array that the object is in.

I'm trying to make a request like this:

```kotlin
restTemplate.postForObject<AbcdResponse>(
    "/address",
    listOf(value).let { JsonHttpEntity(it) }
)
```

```kotlin
data class AbcdResponse(
    val obj: AbcdObject
)
data class DaDataAddress(
    val source: String?
)
```

But I get the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.app.client.abcd.domain.AbcdResponse` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.app.client.abcd.domain.AbcdResponse` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

How can I deserialize the response correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably noticed, the response *as a whole* is a JSON array. You can tell by the square brackets `[ ... ]` surrounding the whole thing.

Because of this, you cannot deserialize it as an object (such as `AbcdResponse`). What you should do instead is use `List<DaDataAddress>` instead of `AbcdResponse`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `AbcdResponse`. What you need is to use a `ParameterizedTypeReference` as follows while calling the service:

```kotlin
restTemplate.exchange("/address", 
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    listOf(value).let { JsonHttpEntity(it) }, 
    ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DaDataAddress>>() {})
```

The reason is that the service that you are calling is returning a JSON array of JSON objects.